# Is it possible to redirect stdio sprintf_s from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, console, stdio

I'm using a C++ dll (not mine) from C#. I'm successfully redirecting the C# console output to a file using `Console.SetOut` and `Console.SetError`.

Is there any way I can force `sprintf_s` to do the same, from the 'outside'?

Answer (score 1):

No, because `sprintf_s` "prints" into a string which the DLL will then use internally for whatever it needs (*sometimes* to send to stdout/err, but generally for lots of other reasons as well).

(Being pedantic, you could possibly do some clever stuff with the linker to make it use your own version of `sprintf_s` that allowed you to snoop on anything sent through it, but that would be getting horribly complicated).